# $\int_0^2 [x]^n f'(x) dx $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate $\int_0^2 [x]^n f'(x) dx$ , where [x] is interger part of x, f '(x) is derivative of f.

1.$ (n+2)^n $(f (2)-f (1))

2. $(1+2^n)$(f (2)-f (1))
3. $2^nf (2) -(2^n-1) f (1) -f (0)$
4. None of these

I need suggestion here. It looks complicated.between 0 and 1 [x] shoud dissapear and between 1 and 2 integrand could be just f '(x).

Comment: Maybe it's [$x^n$]?

Comment: May be, but then n shud have been specified

Comment: Oops, I didn't see answer choice 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
\begin{align*}
\int_0^2[x]^nf'(x)dx&=\int_0^1[x]^nf'(x)dx+\int_1^2[x]^nf'(x)dx\\
&=\int_0^10f'(x)dx+\int_1^21f'(x)dx\\
&=\int_1^2f'(x)dx
\end{align*}